# Connecting Laptop to External Monitor. I/O and GSync issue

Tags: display, hdmi, external-display, displayport, thunderbolt

[image: PhysX Control Panel SS]

I am using Asus TUF F15 2021 (i7 11800H and RTX 3060)

I want to connect to ext monitor which supports 144Hz GSync via DP but no GSync 144Hz via HDMI.

I have a Type C Thunderbolt 4 and an HDMI output in laptop. The SS of NVIDIA Control Panel shows Type C and 2 DP Ports but I don't have DP port on my laptop.

- I am totally confused how to connect and is there any way that I can make use of GSync via DP port on monitor since HDMI output to DP input is not possible (Technologically limited).
- Also, USB C to DP port will be using my Intel Integrated GPU (acc to the image) and won't perform well in games compared to RTX 3060.
- Also, will HDMI to HDMI work? Since below image does not show HDMI port but my laptop has one.

Help much appreciated. Haven't purchased the monitor because of the above confusion but have my eyes on LG 27GN880 Ergo model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same model and GSync works perfectly well (up to 144Hz), connected to an external monitor via Thunderbolt --> DisplayPort cable. Also, the Thunderbolt port IS wired to the Nvidia GPU in this model, so you'll be OK.

As a side note, I didn't notice any major FPS improvement when bypassing the iGPU. *What I did notice was a fairly significant increase in power consumption, so beware!* :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But GSync won't work with HDMI port. I am not after improving fps bypassing iGPU. I want a tear free gameplay.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, finally got it working.

Got a usb-c to DP cable, the trick was not plugging it into the Thunderbolt 4 slot (as you would expect), but the USB-C slot. Now the display settings and G-sync options are showing in the Nvidia control panel.

Only then I found on my laptop's spec sheet that G-sync is supported on the USB-C port, but not the Thunderbolt (although both can be connected to Display Port)